# How to generate delivery report for SMS sent by any SMS app on android

Tags: android, sms, broadcastreceiver, messaging

I am working on a app which is suppose to capture delivery report for SMS sent by any SMS app in the phone.

I have worked on messaging app that sends and also collects delivery report.  It is done by setting pending intent :

```
PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, intent_delivery, 0);
```

and then

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras = arg1.getExtras();
                switch (getResultCode()) {
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    notifyMessage("SMS delivered", getBaseContext(), extras.getInt("id"));

                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    notifyMessage("SMS not delivered", getBaseContext(), extras.getInt("id"));

                    break;
                default :
                    notifyMessage("Unable to generate delivery Report", getBaseContext(), extras.getInt("id"));
                }
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
```

But now I want know how to be able to collect SMS sent by any SMS app installed on phone.

Presently I just have an idea of setting a broadcast listner for this purpose but I don't know how to and what kind of broad cast listner to set and the to check for wht parameter.  I think i have to check PDU for information but i am not sure.  I tried to search the net but i could not find things relevent to my need.

Help me out 
Thank you.